# Understanding git reset --mixed

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to understand the `git reset` command. I understand `git reset --hard`, and I understand that `git reset --soft` is useful very rarely. Despite reading a lot online and on this site, I'm having a hard time understanding what `git reset --mixed` (or simply `git reset`) actually does and what it's used for.

I know `git reset` resets the staging area to that of the specified commit, leaving the working tree as it is in the most recent commit.

What does this actually mean? The staging area contains modified files ready to be committed. However how does it make sense for the working tree to be of a later version than the staging area?

When would I use this command?

It's very confusing. Please try to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have checked-out a branch and edited on your local, but you are not happy with all those changes, and your latest commit was a stable one. In this terrible moment, here comes

`git reset --hard`

to get back to the stable commit, and get rid of all local changes.

## *hard, soft, and mixed are different on what they are resetting*

1. --soft

Just resets your index, and does not touch any of your changed files

2. --mixed

This also resets your index, and does not remove your local changed files too, just un-marks them for committing.

3. --hard

This tough guy just evaporates all of your latest actions, removes the files, resets the index, thus brings back your latest commit.

**Also [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html)**

Comment: Why would I ever want to reset the index and not the working tree?

Comment: Consider you have at couple commits till you are satisfied with your resulting code, but you do not wish to have that many commits, or just unhappy about your past commit details. With --soft, you can get rid of the commits but can still have the changes on your local, and can combine all modification into a single commit.